# Для чего могут быть полезны с ссылки на конструкторы?

Tags: java

На сколько я знаю с java8, с помощью лямбда выражений можно передавать ссылки на конструкторы, но для чего это нужно(имею в виду именно ссылки на конструкторы)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно, вы спрашиваете о конструкции типа `() -> new Object()`?
Это используется для т.н. ленивой инициализации, т.е., когда нужен будет этот объект можно выполнить лямбду и получить инициализированный объект непосредственно в тот момент, когда он будет необходим, например:

```
public static void main(String.. args) {
    foo(() -> new A());
    // ...
}

private static void foo(Supplier supplier) {
    // ...
    A object = supplier.get(); // <-- конструктор будет вызван(и будет выделена память) в этот момент
    // ...
}
```